# Email going to two different mailboxes

Tags: email, dns

I am migrating a client from IMAP email to Hosted Exchange. We updated the DNS last night and mail started flowing into the new mailboxes. For some reason some mail is still going into the old mailboxes and this seems completely random.

Has anyone experienced this before? Does anyone know how I can resolve it?

My current plan is to request that the old mailboxes be removed in the hope that this will force mail into the new box, though that's a bit of a risk...

Hope someone out there can help.

Comment: You will just have to wait for DNS TTL value to expire (client, in this case servers that are sending emails, have old DNS entries cached and there is nothing you can do at this point)

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common case when you update the DNS servers. You will require to await for the complete DNS propagation to happen. This largely depends on the TTL you have on the DNS records.

The best way to approach this ensuring both the old and new systems are in sync until the complete propagation takes place and you don't see any traffic coming at old endpoint.
Post this you can dispose of the old endpoint.